Extract images from cell from Excel file with python
Sorry for my English
So, I have a problem with extracting a few images from cell. I can extract one. Do you know, how can I extract two of them, which contains in one cell?
My code to extract 1:

import openpyxl
from openpyxl_image_loader import SheetImageLoader

pxl_doc = openpyxl.load_workbook('file.xlsx')
sheet = pxl_doc['Лист1']

image_loader = SheetImageLoader(sheet)

image = image_loader.get('C7')
image.show()

I tried to find another function in Internet, but there is only for 1 pic

Check  #11 for fixing #2

There are plenty of questions/answers showing looping through the images (by location, TLC Co-ordinates) using SheetImageLoader. First in the list look for ### Loop to find the images location and copy to the new work book/sheet

Images aren't actually stored in cells.
